# Is iPad 2S already available or not?

Tags: ipad

I thought it would be out only in March but here I can see a video from an University which says they bought 50 iPad 2S
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HhBm9doR6E

So I'm confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You're misreading *2s*. Concordia didn't purchase a new model, they bought multiple units. *iPad 2s* is the plural of iPad 2.

Although the rumor mill continues to grind away there has been no announcement from Apple about the release of the next iPad model, its specifications or release date.

Comment: I'm not english native that's why I did misread :)